# Using useEffect to trigger a re-render by updating state, but cannot have state in dependency array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-maps, react-hooks

```
function Map({latitude, longitude, markers}: MapProps) {

    const [currentZoom, setCurrentZoom] = useState(14);
    const sizeRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const height = sizeRef.current.clientHeight;
        const width = sizeRef.current.clientWidth;
        const zoom = calculateZoomLevel(markers, height, width);
        setCurrentZoom(zoom);
    }, []);

    function onMapChange({zoom}: ChangeEventValue) {
        if (currentZoom !== zoom) {
            setCurrentZoom(zoom);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div ref={sizeRef}>
            <GoogleMapReact
                defaultCenter={{
                    lat: latitude,
                    lng: longitude
                }}
                zoom={currentZoom}
                onChange={onMapChange}
            >
                markers.map(function(marker) {
                    return (<Marker name={marker.name}/>
                });
            </GoogleMapReact>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I am using `google-map-react` with my web app and I am trying to calculate the zoom such that all the map markers are visible on the map, the `calculateZoomLevel` function uses the `google-map-react` API and requires the dimensions of the map in order to calculate the required zoom level. Since I am using server-side rendering I must wait until the React component has mounted until I am able retrieve the dimensions of the map. I cannot use the `window.innerHeight/Width` property.

Therefore, in theory, I must initially render the page with a default zoom level for the map, then once it is mounted I can retrieve the component dimensions, calculate the intended zoom level and then trigger a re-render of the map. I am using functional components along with `useEffect` in order to try and achieve this.

**THIS DOES NOT WORK**

```
const [currentZoom, setCurrentZoom] = useState(14);

useEffect(() => {
    const height = sizeRef.current.clientHeight;
    const width = sizeRef.current.clientWidth;
    const zoom = calculateZoomLevel(markers, height, width);
    setCurrentZoom(zoom);
}, []);
```

**HOWEVER THIS DOES**

```
const [currentZoom, setCurrentZoom] = useState(14);

useEffect(() => {
    const height = sizeRef.current.clientHeight;
    const width = sizeRef.current.clientWidth;
    const zoom = calculateZoomLevel(markers, height, width);
    setCurrentZoom(zoom);
}, [currentZoom]);
```

This would be fine, however the problem is that now `useEffect` is triggered every time that the zoom level is changed on the map (ie: when `onMapChange` is called). When I have an empty dependency array, the `useEffect` runs once after initial render, but does not properly trigger the a re-render with the updated zoom level which was just calculated. It seems that I have to have the `currentZoom` state inside the dependency array for the changes to propagate, but I still have to preserve the functionality of allowing the user to change the zoom on the map.

Comment: Your first snippet should work as you expect. The component is rendered and mounted, then your effect runs, which sets the `currentZoom` state, which should trigger a second render. Add a `console.log('effect ran')` to your effect, and a `console.log('rendered')` to the main body of your component. How many times do each log message you see if after the page loads?

Comment: Try to use `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect`. Also you should check that `sizeRef.current` is not null in your effect. Instead of simple ref you could use callback ref and trigger your effect only after `div` element is actually received / changed. Finally, `onMapChange` should be memoized, otherwise it is recreated on each render (use useCallback for it).

Comment: @AlexWayne, unfortunately the state is not properly updated when I don't have it in the dependency array. I ran the first snippet with the logs that you suggested and it goes, `rendered, effect ran, rendered, rendered`. Really not sure why it's not working

Comment: what if you add `console.log({ width, height, zoom })` to your effect right before you save the state. Are those values what you expect? Also what is sizeRef? how is that set?

Comment: @ArtyomKozhemiakin thanks for the answer, unfortunately useLayoutEffect does not work either. I can confirm that sizeRef.current is not null and the zoom is properly being calculated. It it just either not being updated or the changes are not being reflected.

Comment: @AlexWayne, yes the values before the state is being set are what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

You should put currentZoom in Ref

```
  <GoogleMapReact
            defaultCenter={{
                lat: latitude,
                lng: longitude
            }}
            zoom={currentZoom.current}
            onChange={onMapChange}
        >
```

Note: setState runs asynchronously,
ex: currentZoom = 14
while useEffect setting the currentZoom state. the GoogleMapReact renders but the currentZoom state is still 14 since setting state is not done yet

Comment: sorry, can you elaborate on that? adding currentZoom to ref?